# How to add a Recent Post Slider

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a column for recent post in my Site ( www.example.com ).

How do I add a slider to it using php?

Comment: What error showing jquery slider ?

Comment: Please share error message and the code snippet involved.

Comment: Removed the link to a real site to avoid this post being deleted as spam. Removed references to languages you say you do NOT want to have answers about.